# how to build a mask efficiently

Tags: c#, mask

I have a method in c# with only 1 parameter (it is an override so I cannot change its signature to incorporate more parameters):

```
read_address(long adr)
```

where adr is the address memory I want to read, but I have to pass the address and indicating at the same time if the address to read is 16 or 32 bit and if 32 bits, furthermore I have to indicate if I want to read upper or lower word so I would like to know an efficient way to do this using parameter adr.

I have thought to build a mask, for example, If I want to read address 614 (decimal), I can add two digits before or back:

> 10614 : first digit 1 indicates size=32bit and second one 0=lower word
>   11614 : first digit 1 indicates size=32bit and second one 1=upper word

for indicate 16 bit, no necessary to indicate lower or upper so:

00614 = 614 will indicate 16-bit.

Also I can done this by putting those two digits back:

61410
61411

So when I receive this number through addr parameter I have to parse it to know if this is a 16 or 32 bit and in case of 32 if it is lower or upper word.

EDITED:

I think I haven't explained well...

For example, figure that this method, read_address, receive and address (addr) to read. THis is called from another method, method_A, which knows if this is 16 or 32 bit and if 32 bit it splits into two word. Better an example, for read 614:

```
Method_A(....)
{
   if 16-bit then

   {
       call read_address(620) // Supose 620 is 16 bit
   }

   if 32-bit then

   { 

       // suppose 614 is 32 bit so split into two reads

       call read_address(61410)  // to read first word

       call read_address(61411) // to read second word

   } 

}
```

so in read_address I have to know if it is 16 or 32 bit and if 32-bit, I also have to know if it is lower or upper word.

```
read_address(long addr)

{

    // decode if addr is 16 or 32 bit and if 32 bit, decode if lower

    // or upper word and do some stuff


    // So suppose it arrives 61410... how to decode it in order to know,

    // address to read is 614 and is 32-bit (1) and I want to read lower word (0)


}
```

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "c# - " and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: Is there actually a question in here? If there was, I'd say the answer depends on the possible range of values for `adr`. E.g. for a 32 bit value, adding 10000 would cause a massive heap of troubles.

Comment: There is no scenario where this method *as an override* can function properly.  The caller *has* to know how to mangle the address properly so the method can work.  So it *has* to know that this specific override is going to get called.  At that point there's just no point in making it an override, just add a new method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mention the "upper/higher" word only counts when addr specifies a 32-bit address - I hope you meant it only counts on 16-bits? (if not, how would you know whether the value "10" is a mask or an adress?)

I wouldn't use decimal positions for the mask, but rather split the 64 bits into two 32 bit numbers (integers), and use binary flags.

The example 614 as a 64-bit number in binary would then be (I hope I got the endianness right, but it should illustrate the situation):

```
00000010 00000000 00000000 00000000 01100110 00000010 00000000 00000000
|              Mask               | |            Address              |
```

You can then use a `[Flags] enum` to define the mask, and cast the mask-integer to that enum. Here's an example of creating and parsing the address:

```
    public void Main()
    {
        // Some test values.
        ushort address16 = ushort.MaxValue;
        uint address32 = uint.MaxValue;

        // Upper:
        ulong valueUpper = address16;           // Value contains 0x000000000000FFFF
        valueUpper = valueUpper << 48;          // Value contains 0xFFFF000000000000
        valueUpper += (uint)Mask.Upper;         // Value contains 0xFFFF000000000001

        // Lower:
        ulong valueLower = address16;           // Value contains 0x000000000000FFFF
        valueLower = valueLower << 32;          // Value contains 0x0000FFFF00000000
        // No need to set a 0-bit, it is already 0

        // DWord:
        ulong valueDword = address32;           // Value contains 0x00000000FFFFFFFF
        valueDword = valueDword << 32;          // Value contains 0xFFFFFFFF00000000
        valueDword += (uint)Mask.DoubleWord;    // Value contains 0xFFFFFFFF00000010

        ulong addr1 = ParseAddress((long)valueUpper);
        ulong addr2 = ParseAddress((long)valueLower);
        ulong addr3 = ParseAddress((long)valueDword);
    }

    public ulong ParseAddress(long address)
    {
        // Casting to ulong, as negative values don't make sense in addresses or bitwise operations.
        ulong value = (ulong)address;

        // Take the mask from the least significant bits
        Mask mask = (Mask)(value & uint.MaxValue);

        // Shift the mask bytes "off" the addr, get the remaining address. 
        ulong addr = ((ulong)value >> 32);

        // Is the doubleword bit set?
        if ((mask & Mask.DoubleWord) == Mask.DoubleWord)
        {
            return addr;
        }
        else if ((mask & Mask.Upper) == Mask.Upper)
        {
            return (addr >> 16);
        }
        else
        {
            return addr;
        }
    }

    [Flags]
    public enum Mask : uint
    {
        Upper = 1,
        DoubleWord = 2,
    }
```

Comment: I have been thinking about your solution and I think it is more maintainable and efficient but I don't understand you very well... could you provide a very little example, for construct the address with the mask (upper and lower cases for double word) and then extract the address and check if it is lower or upper double word? thanks very very much for your help

Comment: @user304602 see my modified post for a working example. Again I hope the lower/upper thing applies to the 16 bit values, not the 32 bit ones, otherwise you're screwed.

Answer (score 0):

> it is an override so I cannot change its signature to incorporate more
>   parameters

Although you can't override a virtual method and change its signature at the same time, you **can** define an overload in your subclass that takes those extra parameters. e.g.:

```
class SuperClass
{
    public virtual void read_address(long adr)
    {

    }
}

class SubClass : SuperClass
{
    public override void read_address(long adr)
    {
        // call the overload with your default values e.g. 32 and false
        this.read_address(adr, 32, false);
    }

    public void read_address(long adr, int bytesToRead, bool upper)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```